# empty function object in python

Tags: python, function, design-patterns

I've heard that python functions are objects, similar to lists or dictionaries, etc.  However, what would be a similar way of performing this type of action with a function?

```
# Assigning empty list to 'a'
a = list()

# Assigning empty function to 'a'
a = lambda: pass
# ???
```

How would you do this? Further, is it necessary or proper?
Here is the sense in which I would like to use it for better context:

I have a `QListWidget` for selecting items which are associated with keys in a dictionary. The values in this dictionary are also dictionaries, which hold certain properties of the items, which I can add. These certain properties are stored as keys, and the values in them are initialized or updated by calling different functions.  So, I'm storing a variable in the window which gets updated when a button is pressed to tell this script which property to update.

As you can see, I would like to store the function to map to the data using the correct function based on the situation.

```
# Get selection from the list
name = selected_item
# Initialize an empty function
f = lambda: pass
# Use property that is being added now, which was updated by the specific button that was pushed
property_list = items[name][self.property_currently_being_added]
if self.property_currently_being_added == "prop1":
    f = make_property1()
elif self.property_currently_being_added == "prop2":
    f = make_property2()
elif self.property_currently_being_added == "prop3":
    f = make_property3()
elif self.property_currently_being_added == "prop4":
    f = make_property4()

# map the certain function to the data which was retrieved earlier
added_property = map(f, data)
property_list.append(added_property)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need an "empty" function? You certainly *can* do this, exactly as you have written, but why do you need to? Is your function liable to be called when it is not yet properly defined?

Comment: I agree with Henry, there doesn't seem to be a big reason to do this. In your example, you could simply do `else: raise ValueError` or etc. It doesn't seem like you'd want this function to continue if `self.property_currently_being_added == None` or what-have-you.

Comment: Also, there's no reason this has to be a lambda. You can just as easily write `def f(): pass`, with the same effect. The only reasons to ever use `lambda` are (a) you don't want to give the function a name (doesn't apply here; you immediately assign it to `f`); (b) you need to define it in an expression, not a statement (doesn't apply here; you use it directly in an assignment statement); or (c) you're taking a class with a professor who hates Python and would rather be teaching Scheme (presumably doesn't apply here).

Comment: Thank you, that's certainly helpful.  I suppose I will just leave the function to only be applied when certain cases are met.

Comment: You can make an identity function.  But you are really barking up the wrong tree with lambda.

Comment: As a side note, is `make_property1()` actually a function that returns a function? If so, is there a good reason you need four separate functions rather than `make_property(1)` or `make_property('prop1')`? One of the latter would probably be a lot cleaner…

Comment: @HenryKeiter: He can't do this exactly as written; `lambda: pass` is a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Just for fun, if you really want a _truly_ empty function object, try this: `c = types.CodeType(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, b'', (), (), (), '<main>', 'f', 0, b'')`, then `f = types.FunctionType(c, {})`. Of course all this function does is raise a `SystemError` when called… but how useful do you expect an empty function to be? :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, the reason this doesn't work:

```
a = lamdba: pass
```

… is that [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) only allows an expression, and defines a function that returns the value of the expression. Since [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-pass-statement) is a statement, not an expression, this is illegal.

However, this works just fine:

```
a = lambda: None
```

In Python, a function that falls off the end without a `return` statement always returns `None`. So, these are equivalent:

```
def a(): return None
def a(): pass
```

However, I don't see why you want to write this as a lambda and an assignment anyway; the `def` is shorter, and more readable, and gives you an introspectable function object with a nice name (`a` instead of `<lambda>`), and so on. The only reasons to ever use `lambda` are when you don't want to give the function a name, or when you need to define the function inside an expression. Obviously neither of those are true, because you use the `lambda` directly inside an assignment statement. So, just use `def`.

---

Meanwhile, this is in a sense an "empty function", or at least as empty as possible (as you can see by, e.g., calling `dis.dis(a)`, it still takes two bytecodes to do nothing but fall off the end and return `None`), but it's not useful for your case. You don't want an "empty function". If you try passing your `a` to `map`, you're just going to get a `TypeError`, because you're trying to call a function of no arguments with one argument. (Because that's what `map` does.)

What you might want is an *identity* function, which just returns its argument as-is. Like this:

```
def a(x): return x
```

But I'm not sure that's what you want. Did you want to append `data` as-is in that case? Or did you want to do something different, like return early, or raise an exception, or not append anything, or …?

---

Finally, I don't see why you want a function at all. Why not just not call `map` if you have nothing to map? You have a perfectly good `else` clause that already catches that case (especially handy if what you want to do is return early or raise…). Or, if you prefer, you can start with `f = None`, and then use an `if f:` do decide whether to map or not. Or, if you really want:

```
added_property = [f(element) if f else element for element in data]
```

… or …

```
added_property = map(f, data) if f else data
```

---

As one last note, instead of a long `if`/`elif` chain that repeats the same thing over and over again, you might want a `dict`:

```
propfuncs = {'prop1': make_property1(),
             'prop2': make_property2(),
             'prop3': make_property3(),
             'prop4': make_property4()}
```

Then, all that cruft turns into these two lines:

```
f = propfuncs.get(self.property_currently_being_added)
added_property = map(f, data) if f else data
```

Or course an even better design might be to replace all those `make_propertyN` functions with a single function that you call as `make_property(1)` or `make_property('prop1')`… but without seeing what they actually do, I can't be sure of that.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert This is an excellent answer.  Good call on the `propfuncs` idea, I think that may help. The functions `make_propertyN()` are actually functions which just initialize other nested dictionaries, but I think this is a good approach for my specific case and hopefully it will help others along this route as well.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness and since the title is "empty function object in python", more general case is an *empty function object that takes any number of parameters*, so you can use it in *any* callback. It's this one:

```
callback = lambda *_, **__: None
```

Explanation is here: http://echochamber.me/viewtopic.php?t=64825

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised to learn that you can even do...

```
def a(): "This is a test"

a()
```

Answer (score 0):

this feels so much like you're looking for a `Nothing` functor, I am guessing that if you had knowledge of Monads you wouldn't even need an empty function , as inspiration [PyMonad](https://bitbucket.org/jason_delaat/pymonad/src/cbecd6796cd1488237d2a0f057cefd2a50df753a/pymonad/Maybe.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) has a nice `Nothing` implementation, I usually like to create my own, but it's a good starting point.